# Convert list with distances and seconds to list of kilometers with pace

Tags: c#

Imagine a list with distances and the time in seconds that belongs to it.

**meterTempos**

```
{
    distance: 500,
    seconds: 50
},
{
    distance: 600
    seconds: 60
}
```

The above list can be any number of 'distance-seconds'- items. This is just an example not hardcoded data.

My question is, how do I convert it to the following format?

**kmTempos**

```
{
    km: 1,
    distance: 1000,
    seconds: 100
}, {
    km: 2,
    distance: 100,
    seconds: 10
}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
double totaldistance = 1100; //Total distance is variable, but for the sake of simplicity, I set it to 1.1
int loops = (int)(Math.Ceiling(totaldistance / 1000));

List<KilometerTempo> kmTempos = new List<KilometerTempo>();
for (int j = 0; j < loops; j++)
{
    double seconds = meterTempos[j].seconds;
    double distance = meterTempos[j].meters;
//this is definitely wrong, since it will add new KilometerTempos for every item in meterTempos
    kmTempos.Add(new KilometerTempo(j + 1, distance, seconds));
}
```

As you can see, I dont understand how to iterate over the list and work with a subresult that should be taken into account for every new kilometer.

Comment: Why does 50 meter seconds turn into 100 km seconds? And 60 turns into 10?

Comment: Are these values like checkpoint values along a run (or something?)

Comment: @AndrewJenkins, the first list should be normalized. Since 500 meters in the first list is not enough to create 1 new kmTempo, it needs data from the second item in the list. 500 + 600 = 1100 which is sufficient, but I only need 1000 of it.

Comment: @BugFinder Exactly, it actually uses gps data (list of pointf + date)

Comment: `var distance = meterTempos.Sum(v => v.Distance); var time = meterTempos.Sum(v => v.Seconds); var v = distance / time;` ?

Comment: @m.rogalski this does not work, it really needs to produce a new list with normalized data. E.g: km number 1 in 100 seconds, km number 2 in 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<KilometerTempo> kmTempos = new List<KilometerTempo>();

foreach (MeterTempo mt in meterTempos)
{
    double rDistance = mt.distance; // remaining distance to add

    while (rDistance > 0)
    {
        if (kmTempos.Count == 0 || kmTempos.Last().distance == 1000f)
        {
            kmTempos.Add(new KilometerTempo());
            kmTempos.Last().km = kmTempos.Count;
        }
        // determine max distance we can add to the last km tempo
        double maxAddedDistance = 1000f - kmTempos.Last().distance;
        // determine how much we will add
        double addedDistance = rDistance < maxAddedDistance ? rDistance : maxAddedDistance;
        kmTempos.Last().distance += addedDistance;
        // add seconds proportional to the added distance
        kmTempos.Last().seconds += (addedDistance / mt.distance) * mt.seconds;
        rDistance -= addedDistance;
    }

}
```